# Redirecting to load views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Say for example i have my homepage view. Inside the homepage view i have a data list to paginate and also more data to pass to the view.

So in my pages controller(for loading views from html links like 'home' for example/ 'login' etc.)

```
public function home(){
//pagination here
//process data here to pass to navbar
$data['title'] = 'homepage';
$this->load->view('template/header',$data);
$this->load->view('template/navbar',$data);
$this->load->view('pages/home',$data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

The data passed to the navbar is a notifcation of sorts since i plan to add a notifcation dropdown on the navbar for the user logged in so every page i access i have to process the notification data and pass it to my navbar.

Let's just say for example after logging in:

```
public function login(){
//*validate data*
//*get data*
//*process data*
$result = $this->model->login($data);
if($result == TRUE){ //*db get where in model returns true if data entered exists* 

redirect('pages/home');}
}
```

Am i doing it right? i know it works because im doing this in my logout function where after destroying the session i just redirected to the pages controller to view home.

Therefore this makes my code and potentially if this is acceptable method will reduce all of my code by atleast 30% because the reason why most of my code are very long because of the data i have to paginate not to mention the data i will have to process for the planned functions im adding like notification so in all functions ive done after every success if i have to load a page that needs all these data then my code will get 50% longer that is unnecessary to the function.

for example the code above for login, if the code above doesnt work then i'll have to add pagination + more data processing before loading the view homepage so the code will get longer but only 20-40% of it is relevant to the function.

This is what some of my function looked like before i added pagination.php to my config file for the customization:

```
public function sample(){
//process data
if($data){//success
    $num_rows = $this->model->count_rows('table',null);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 6;
    $config['num_links'] = $num_rows;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='page-item active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</a></li>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $query = $this->db->get('table', $config['per_page'],$offset);

    $data['title'] = 'page title';
    $this->load->view('template/header',$data); //passing header title
    $this->load->view('template/navbar'); //will be passing more data here for planned function
    $this->load->view('pages/pagename', $data) /passing pagination data;
    $this->load->view('template/footer');}
    else{//if function fail redirects to the view
    $num_rows = $this->model->count_rows('table',null);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 6;
    $config['num_links'] = $num_rows;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='page-item active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</a></li>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $query = $this->db->get('table', $config['per_page'],$offset);

    $data['title'] = 'page title';
    $this->load->view('template/header',$data); //passing header title
    $this->load->view('template/navbar'); //will be passing more data here for planned function
    $this->load->view('pages/pagename', $data) /passing pagination data;
    $this->load->view('template/footer');}
    }
```

That's already long without taking into account the actual codes for the specific function. If say its a login function that redirects to the homepage(where there are paginated data).

What im doing right now and is my question is if its okay to do it like this:

pages controller:

```
public function view(){
    $num_rows = $this->model->count_rows('table',null);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 6;
    $config['num_links'] = $num_rows;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='page-item active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</a></li>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $query = $this->db->get('table', $config['per_page'],$offset);

    $data['title'] = 'page title';
    $this->load->view('template/header',$data); //passing header title
    $this->load->view('template/navbar'); //will be passing more data here for planned function
    $this->load->view('pages/pagename', $data) /passing pagination data;
    $this->load->view('template/footer');}
```

another controller:

```
public function sample(){
//process data
if(success){
redirect('pages/view);
}else{
redirect('pages/view);
}
}
```

Now i have alot more room for the actual codes of the function.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Yes, you can redirect to a controller that loads a view...

Comment: I'm asking if what i'm doing is acceptable since CI is MVC. I just thought of using this method because my codes are very long but the reason is because of all the data i have to paginate and process before passing to the view regardless if they are relevant to the function. So a simple function that could be coded in a few lines will get extended to a few tens of lines. 5 lines of code could get more than 20. It's frustrating to follow my code because of this.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. You keep saying "paginate" but I don't get the relation to your question "Redirecting to load views in codeigniter" or your code.. Please revise for clarity, and remove all unnecessary info that isn't pertinent to your question.

Comment: @ChiefMakii, if I'm not wrong, you are saying that you have a navigation panel common in all pages where you rendering the data. So your problem is you have to write the code to fetch it in every function and pass it every view. Am I right??

Comment: @prabhu Yes, that is my problem. Since some of my views paginate data whenever i have a function that loads that specific view i have to copy paste those long codes again. So i have to repeat same code over and over again if i have to redirect to that view.

Comment: Say for example in a sample function. I have to account for the failure and success of the function but at both times i redirect to a paginated view. So in this case its really annoying since i have to copy paste the pagination code twice in the same function. (i havent added more functions yet because of this since those function relate to the navbar which is global to all views so not only do i deal with the pagination i also have to deal with the data i pass to my navbar every single page i load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution.

Firstly create a helper class under `application/helpers` say `custom_helper`. Then autoload the helper class in `autoload.php` under `application/config`

`$autoload['helper'] = array('custom');`

In `custom_helper` write a function say `disp_navigation`

```
if ( ! function_exists('disp_navigation')){
  function disp_navigation(){ //pass any parameter you wish
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('your-model-name');  //if needed

    //paste all your code which you are using to render the navigation contents.
  }
}
```

Please note that `$this` variable is not accessible in the helper class, so you must use `$CI` in place of `$this`.

Once helper class is all set, call the function anywhere in the view.

```
<html>
<body>
//call the disp_navigation
<?php echo disp_navigation(); ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

You can `echo` or `return` the result from the function and perform whatever operation you want to.

This is really helpful because you can make changes only once and it gets reflected everywhere in the application.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my post a little. I was asking whether or not the way i am loading my view above was correct where i am using redirect() method to call pages controller where all my views are loaded. So for example if login() function either successful or fail will simply redirect to pages controller login_user() function where i put the code for loading that page. This suits my purpose because on my login() function on my account controller i can exclusively write the codes for logging in there whilst not populating the function with the unnecessary data to load the view.

Comment: But your answer is also helpful because i am adding a notifications dropbox to my navbar soon so i will need a way soon to only code it once and have it implemented globally.

Is there a specific reason to use helper? i've seen people sometimes use the library folder if they want to make a function global to the project. I also saw CI_loader and i don't know what it is? are they different?

Comment: You have already used the `CI_loader` in your code. `$this->load->view()`, `$this->load->model()` etc. It is used to load the classes.

Comment: Difference between library and helper is that helper consists of just functions, not classes and they are similar to any other functions that you write inside your controller. Helpers help you to create and access globally. In case of the library, you must have used some functionalities like email, database, sessions etc.  These libraries contain classes and functions that are used for specific purpose. In your case, it is better to use just helpers for defining one function

Comment: Okay, i'll keep that in mind. 

but a question, can you look at my edited question above probably the latter half. I've added codes there in contrast to show if it is correct?

Comment: Your question is bit confusing. But I hope my answer helps you to some extent in the notification. So it may be helpful for other community users if you upvote or accept my answer.